# Running exe inside WinForm Project Tab

Tags: c#, winforms, process, tabs, exe

I am interested in assistance in doing the following with a winform application I am writing to open in a tab an .exe in c# in the Visual Studios 2010 IDE.

I'm currently able to open the program via button click in the desired tab using the following code:

```
        string str = @"-INSERT FILEPATH HERE-";//took file path out as i have a few exes i'm wanting to add. 
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = str;
        process.Start();
```

now how can i make it so this executable opens as the tab or in a tab, in my winform? I'm open to suggestions to doing either case.

SOLVED:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Threading;
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, bool repaint);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

   public GUI()
    {
        // Initialize form fieds
        InitializeComponent();
        openProgram()
    }
    private void openProgram()
    {

        process.StartInfo.FileName = "-filepathhere-";

        process.Start();

        IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
        while ((ptr = process.MainWindowHandle) == IntPtr.Zero) ;
        SetParent(process.MainWindowHandle, trackerPanel.Handle);
        MoveWindow(process.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, this.Width - 90, this.Height, true);

    }
```

Comment: did you mean by using the `TabControl` in `winforms`?

Comment: yeah, I'd like it to be in tab control as a tab.

Comment: so you're trying to open the notepad inside the TabControl, you could try to use the `richTextBox` for that task.

Comment: not notepad, but yes a program needs to open in the tabcontrol.

Comment: Hi @PhoenixLament, can your own answer looks awesome.  Can you provide more details,  I paste the code on my form but get errors related to namespaces.  I already imported user32.dll,  however the same as you, can't instantiate any app just inside a panel.  Thanks

Comment: @datelligence this was a long time ago, but if you'd like to send me your project, i can look at it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the SetParent api to set the parent of the executable's window. Add a panel to your TabControl and use the code below to assign the parent of the executable window to that of the panel.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
    process.Start();
    SetParent(process.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle);
}
```

To remove the window from the panel, use the same code but set the parent handle as IntPtr.Zero

```
SetParent(process.MainWindowHandle, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Comment: The code provided still opens notepad as a new window. Still trying to get this in a panel on the tabcontrol.