# Adding a form to TabPage inside a TabControl

Tags: vb.net, tabcontrol, tabpage

I've create a form in VB.NET that can be initialised multiple times and in order to keep all the open forms organised, I need to use TabControl.

How can I add this form dynamically to a TabPage in the TabControl (similar to a browser)?

Thanks.

Comment: I know this isn't for an exe but see if this post works, set the child form.Handle's parent to TabControl.Handle http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393707/running-exe-inside-winform-project-tab/15396680#15396680

Comment: I would suggest a user control...not docking forms inside tabpages, just a suggestion.

Comment: Or do you want to use the isMdiContainer ? to organize or your Child Form, just giving some alternative ideas =D